# How to send custom currency type to Paypal using Magento Paypal express checkout?

Tags: php, magento, express-checkout, paypal

Is there any way to send Paypay custom currency type other that base currency?

***Here is what i want to achieve.***

Currently i have set my Magento Base currency as `EURO` in `System -> General -> Currency Setup -> Currency Options`. As my client wants to enter Prices in EURO.

Paypay Express checkout takes `EURO` as the currency type while checkout because it takes base currency for prcessing. But we would like to process Payment in `USD`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance!